# What does $u^+$ mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

I see the following statement in Evans' book on PDEs:

> If $Lu\leq 0$ in $U$, then $$\max_{\overline{U}} u=\max_{\partial\overline{U}} u^+$$

What does $u^+$ mean? Is it the set of points where $u$ is positive?

Comment: It is the positive part of $u$, $\max\{u,0\}$.

Comment: @GReyes- Thanks so much!